# how to compare two dates and time in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios5

here is what I am trying

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDate *serDate;
NSDate *endDate;
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
serDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"2012-12-07 7:17:58"];
endDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"2012-12-07 08:43:30"];
int remainigSecond =[endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:serDate];
NSString * Hrs = @"1.30";// is Hrs
if (remainigSecond>3600*[Hrs intValue])
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
```

it does not response expected... Can you help he whats wrong in this please

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by "does not response expected"? Doesn't it compile? Does it crash when run? Does it return the wrong result? If yes, what do you expect? Please be more specific.

Comment: I mean to say when i try to compair those value like this "remainigSecond>3600*[Hrs intValue]" it should return me value 1

Comment: I think you wanted to use 1.5 not 1.3

Comment: @Akii_iOS: Note that `[Hrs intValue]` doesn't make much sense. It returns 1 (and not 1.3), discarding the fractional part of the number. I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: @Codo I am just trying to compair two seconds. now did you got me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSDate *serDate;

    NSDate *endDate;

    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    serDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"2012-12-07 7:17:58"];

    endDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"2012-12-07 08:43:30"];
    NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:serDate];

    double minutes = timeDifference / 60;

    double hours = minutes / 60;

    double seconds = timeDifference;

    double days = minutes / 1440;
    NSLog(@" days = %.0f,hours = %.2f, minutes = %.0f,seconds = %.0f", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
```

and compare like bellow..

```
if (hours > 1.30)
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
```

and the outPut is  `days = 0, hours = 1.43,  minutes = 86,seconds =  5132`

Comment: @Akii_iOS you can get whole property of date-time see answer and just put the condition with second and also with hours.. i hope this useful to you..

Comment: thnks for reply Paras sir but what when I try this
NSString * Hrs = @"1.30";// is Hrs
if (remainigSecond>3600*[Hrs intValue])
    return 1;
else
    return 0;

Comment: just use the condition which i post dude i update the code see and also i understand what u want if hours greater then 1.30 then it will return 1 right?? so its works like your requirement dude..

Comment: @Akii_iOS use this condition dude.. if (hours > 1.30)
    return 1;
else
    return 0;

Comment: Bro I try 2012-12-07 10:15:52 and 2012-12-07 8:47:00 its return me 1.48 Hrs.

Comment: @Akii_iOS what u exactly want?

Comment: 8:47 + 1:48 = 10:15 is it??

Answer (score 8):

compare: function can be used to compare two dates effectively.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDate *serDate;
NSDate *endDate;
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
serDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"2012-12-07 7:17:58"];
endDate = [formatter dateFromString:@"2012-12-07 08:43:30"];

if([serDate compare:endDate])
    NSLog(@"Enddate bigger than serdate");
else
    NSLog(@"serdate bigger than enddate");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get **YEAR**, **MONTH** ana **DAY** etc between two dates

```
 NSCalendar *sysCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit;

    NSDateComponents *conversionInfo = [sysCalendar components:unitFlags fromDate:firstDate  toDate:secondDate  options:0];

    NSLog(@"Conversion: %dmin %dhours %ddays %dmoths %dYear",[conversionInfo minute], [conversionInfo hour], [conversionInfo day], [conversionInfo month]%12,[conversionInfo month]/12);
    NSString *result2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d year, %d month and %d day",[conversionInfo month]/12,[conversionInfo month]%12,[conversionInfo day]];
```

Answer (score 0):

`timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` function works very good in date comparision on two date object.

```
if(([endDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - [startDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]) > 3600*[Hrs intValue]){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(([endDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - [startDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]) > 3600*[Hrs intValue])
{

}
```